# WPF вставка изображения из файла ресурсов

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, изображения

Всем привет. На главной форме у меня есть меню, и я пытаюсь сделать иконку для элемента.

```
<MenuItem Header="Добавить издательство" Width="auto" Command="local:WindowCommands.AddHouse" Height="33" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image Source="Resources/ic_store_black_36dp_2x.png" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" />
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

В конструкторе показывает картинку, но при запуске приложения она не отображается. Что я делаю не так ? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А как именно вы объявили картинку? Как Resource или Embedded Resource? Это важно.

Comment: Загрузил в ресурсы, и в свойствах указал внедрение в .resx

Comment: Не, вы делаете что-то не то. Просто положить картинку в проект, в папку Resources.

Comment: просто перенёс картинку в папу Resources, ничего не изменилось,всё также

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не должны использовать ресурсы из свойств проекта, это даст вам лишь нативные ресурсы, которые подходят для WinForms, но не WPF.

Делайте вот как:

1. Создайте каталог `Resources` в проекте, и добавьте туда файл через Add → Existing Item.
2. Убедитесь, что тип файла выбран как Resource (а не Embedded Resource)

   [image: Ресурсы! Мы хотим ресурсы!]
3. Укажите в XAML путь:

   ```
   <Image Source="Resources/redsquare.png"/>
   ```
4. Результат:

   [image: PROFIT!]