# IOException: Не удается найти ресурс

Tags: c#

Закинул изображение в папку Images, но выдаёт такую ошибку, что делать?-
IOException: Не удается найти ресурс "windows/courseproject/images/button.png".

```
    <Image Margin="-76,10,170,8" >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source"  Value="CourseProject/Images/button.png"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="CourseProject/Images/kupi.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Comment: Это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583151/10105?

Comment: Делал так - не работает.

Comment: Значит, где-то опечатка. Покажите структуру проекта и свойства png-файла, а? Например, вы пишете, что файл в каталоге Images, в XAML у вас невесть откуда взялся CourseProject, а в сообщении об ошибке — windows. Это выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: При вводе просто Images/button.png - он выдавал мне, что не нашёл путь и поэтому я добавил ещё CourseProject. A windows я вообще не понял откуда он взял)

Comment: Ну так напишите путь правильно, и поставьте правильный тип файла. Должно работать.

Comment: Я вроде бы всё сделал, как по обучающему видео, но всё равно не работает. Я бы скинул фото ошибки, но тут нельзя(

Comment: Фото ошибки ничего не даст. Скиньте структура проекта и свойства png-файла. И я бы лично не рекомендовал учиться по видео, они все шлак.

Comment: В общем покопался сам и теперь при полном пути до папки выводит картинку, не знаю почему тогда не работало.